# MySQL update not updating

Tags: mysql

The select works and returns 1 result.

```
SELECT * FROM `list` WHERE `email` = 'john@doe.com' AND `cid` = 1;
```

This update works, no errors, no records affected!!!

```
UPDATE `list` 
  SET `message` = 'test', `status` = 0 
WHERE `email` = 'john@doe.com' AND `cid` = 1;
```

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `list` (
    `id` BIGINT(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cid` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `message` TEXT NULL,
    `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `cid` (`cid`),
    INDEX `date` (`date`),
    INDEX `status` (`status`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: Can you post table definition? `SHOW CREATE TABLE list`

Comment: Also, are you sure that you are actually *changing* some of those values? MySQL will report separately how many rows it matched, and how many it changed. If they are different, then the data simply didn't need to be changed.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev this is a MySQL question, not a programming question. That is exactly the query run on MySQL directly. See answer no.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL server reports no records were affected because, even though one row matches the criteria, it doesn't need to be updated: it already has `message` = 'test' and `status` = 0.

Try this query if you want to **always** update the date field:

```
UPDATE `list` 
  SET `message` = 'test', `status` = 0, `date`=NOW()
WHERE `email` = 'john@doe.com' AND `cid` = 1;
```

Comment: OK, good answer, makes sense, spare the server the need to use extra resources. GOT A SOLUTION? I want the TIMSTAMP to update the date field either way.

Comment: if you want to update the date field, then it should be part of your update query.

Comment: What if I do not wish to provide the time, I want MySQL to do it.