# Laravel - Show update message after update using query builder

Tags: laravel

In my laravel + vue application I am trying to update the **name** and **account_external_id** column in mysql database.

Here is the code:

```
// Set the database name and id project
$db_name = $get_db->mysql_db_name;
$id_project = $get_db->id_project;

// Update linked account
$update_linked_account = DB::connection($db_name)
->table($db_name . '.linked_accounts')
->where('id_linked_account', $id_linked_account)
->where('id_project', $id_project )
->update([
    'name'  =>  $account_name, 
    'account_external_id'   =>  $account_id
]);
                
// If updated
if( $update_linked_account ) {
    return response()->json([
        'success'   =>  true, 
        'message'   =>  'Account updated successfully.'
    ], 200);
} else {
    return response()->json([
        'success'   =>  false, 
        'message'   =>  'Could not update the account.'
    ], 200);
}
```

When I change the **name** or **account_external_id** value then press the **update** button then I can get the `$update_linked_account` as `true`.

**BUT**

When I do not change the **name** or **account_external_id** value then press the **update** button then I can get the `$update_linked_account` as `false`. why? It should give me `true` too, right?

Comment: Yes, I understand why its not showing me true and now I have change my way to show message to the user. Thanks anyway.

Comment: [MySQL update not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376733/mysql-update-not-updating)

Comment: For `->update(...)` and `->delete(...)` calls, the return value is the [*number of affected rows*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33462806/7376590).